# Passing parameter onChange using useParams in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement search functionality.
I have the navbar component in searchResult component. In navbar there is a search field.
I am trying to call a 5 function simultaneously which update single state. But in my code results are not getting updated.

Navbar.js

```
 <Link to={`/search/${searchField}`} >
        <li className="nav-item">
          <form id="search-bar">
            <input
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search"
              onChange={(e) => setSearchField(e.target.value)}
            />
          </form>
        </li>
      </Link>
```

SearchResult.js

```
 const { value } = useParams();
 const { searchResults, setSearchResults } = useContext(search);
 const findMemberFunction = (value) => {
 let dataToSubmit = {
  referCode: value,
};
dispatch(findMember(dataToSubmit.referCode))
  .then((response) => {
    let allSearchResult = searchResults;

    response.payload.members.map((item) => {
      allSearchResult.members.push(item);
    });

    setSearchResults(allSearchResult);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("err", error);
  });
 };
 const findSearchTagFunction = (value) => {
let dataToSubmit = {
  name: value,
};
dispatch(findTags(dataToSubmit.name))
  .then((response) => {
    let allSearchResult = searchResults;
    response.payload.tags.map((item) => {
      allSearchResult.tags.push(item);
    });

    setSearchResults(allSearchResult);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("err", error);
  });
 };
const findGroupFunction = (value) => {
let dataToSubmit = {
  name: value,
};
dispatch(findGroup(dataToSubmit.name))
  .then((response) => {
    let allSearchResult = searchResults;
    response?.payload?.groups.map((item) => {
      allSearchResult.groups.push(item);
    });

    setSearchResults(allSearchResult);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("err", error);
  });
 };
  const findEventFunction = (value) => {
let dataToSubmit = {
  name: value,
};
dispatch(findEvent(dataToSubmit.name))
  .then((response) => {
    let allSearchResult = searchResults;
    response.payload.events.map((item) => {
      allSearchResult.events.push(item);
    });

    setSearchResults(allSearchResult);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("err", error);
  });
 };
 const findContentFunction = (value) => {
let dataToSubmit = {
  name: value,
   };
    dispatch(findContent(dataToSubmit.name))
  .then((response) => {
    let allSearchResult = searchResults;
    response.payload.contents.map((item) => {
      allSearchResult.contents.push(item);
    });

    setSearchResults(allSearchResult);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log("err", error);
  });
 };
 useEffect(() => {
findMemberFunction(value);
findSearchTagFunction(value);
findGroupFunction(value);
findEventFunction(value);
findContentFunction(value);
  }, [value]);
```

This is not working as i am expecting to have parameter onChange.

Comment: Is `searchResults` component that which is rendered on the route that the navbar `Link to={\`/search/${searchField}\`}` links to? Can you show how this Route is defined?

Comment: <Route exact path="/search/:value" component={SearchResult} />

Comment: Unless you've done something weird like use more than one `Router` component I don't see an issue with routing to the `path="/search/:value"` route and accessing the `value` match param. Now the issue I see is that the `useEffect` hook in `SearchResult` seems to call several functions that all eventually set the `searchResults` state, asynchronously. (*Which I just realized now is what you said you're trying to do*) What isn't working as expected then? What is the issue? Do these actions need to be called in a specific order?

Comment: The issue is when I type in the search field it's not calling all the functions onChange. and also it's not passing all the alphabets which I type in search field .

Comment: const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState({
    members: [],
    tags: [],
    groups: [],
    events: [],
    contents: [],
  });
I want to set these arrays based on the function and also simultaneously when I type something on search field this function has to be called all at once.

Comment: Seems the `onChange` calls only one function, `onChange={(e) => setSearchField(e.target.value)}` to update the `searchField` state value. The link doesn't do anything until you click on it to trigger a navigation action. Also, the way you've coded your `setSearchResults(allSearchResult);` state updates, they all will overwrite the state from any previous concurrent call, the last update to be written is the one you'll see. I think you need to take a step back and rethink the UX a bit. If you want the search to be live then it can't be passed through the URL to `SearchResults`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. do you have other suggestions on how I can code setSearchResults?

Comment: Use a [functional state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) so each callback can update a specific chunk of sub-state, i.e. `setSearchResults(results => ({ ...results, members: /* new members state */ }))`. This is so each update updates from the previous state versus the state from the render cycle they were all enqueued in.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working perfectly.